# Numerical exception handler java

Tags: java

I want to see if the input is a number and if not to re ask for a number but i cant find how to do it

```
System.out.println("Enter three numbers: ");

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int n1 = sc.nextInt();
int n2 = sc.nextInt();
int n3 = sc.nextInt();
sc.close();
int smallest;
            
if(n1<n2) {
    if(n3<n1) {
        smallest = n3;
    } else {
        smallest = n1;
    }
} else {
    if(n2<n3) {
        smallest = n2;
    } else {
        smallest = n3;
    }
}
    
System.out.println("The smallest number is: " + smallest);
```

I tried some things but no results

Comment: You can read a line, convert it to integer and catch a numberformatexception, if that's the case, ask for another number

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put the user input into a try-catch block and then catch a `InputMismatchException` which is thrown by `nextInt()` if the user input is not a valid Integer.

```
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
     int n = sc.nextInt();
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {

}
```

Comment: What do i have to put inside the catch?